# Storing file created date in Azure File Storage

Tags: azure, azure-files

I am storing a series of Excel files in an Azure File Storage container for my company. My manager wants to be able to see the file created date for these files, as we will be running monthly downloads of the same reports. Is there a way to automate a means of storing the created date as one of the properties in Azure, or adding a bit of custom metadata, perhaps? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly store the created date as part of custom metadata for the file. However, there are certain things you would need to be aware of:

- **Metadata is editable**: Anybody with access to the storage account can edit the metadata. They can change the created date metadata value or even delete that information.
- **Querying is painful**: Azure File Storage doesn't provide querying capability so if you want to query on file's created date, it is going to be a painful process. First you would need to list all files in a share and then fetch metadata for each file separately. Depending on the number of files and the level of nesting, it could be a complicated process.

There are some alternatives available to you:

**Use Blob Storage**

If you can use Blob Storage instead of File Storage, use that. Blob Storage has a system defined property for created date so you don't have to do anything special. However like File Storage, Blob Storage also has an issue with querying but it is comparatively less painful.

**Use Table Storage/SQL Database For Reporting**

For querying purposes, you can store the file's created date in either Azure Table Storage or SQL Database. The downside of this approach is that because it is a completely separate system, it would be your responsibility to keep the data in sync. For example, if a file is deleted, you will need to ensure that entry for the same in the database is also removed.